# avl trees rotations question

Tags: binary-search-trees, avl-trees

[image]

As you can see in this tree its unbalanced at the root with a balanced factor of $-2$. You can also perform a Right left rotation or a Right Right rotation. Which do you have to pick in this case?

Comment: If you're following a certain algorithm, you have to pick what the algorithm specifies. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by "have to". It's a free world. You don't have to do anything. If you're just looking for an operation that improves the balance factor, then you could just apply both and checks which of them works, if any.

Comment: @Tinler How about a left rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you want to rebalance the AVL tree.

You can either do [a simple left rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Simple_rotation) or [a right-left rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Double_rotation).

I prefer not to mention right-right rotation since that term is misleading and ambiguous.

You can visualize what is happening. Go to [AVL tree visualization](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html), a page created by David Galles. Insert 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 in that order. Now look closely when you delete 1.
[image]